# Disabling "glue" and other vertical space adjustment?

Tags: spacing

I'm making a template that I can use for my résumé and CV which uses a horizontal line underneath section titles.  I'm running into a problem where, when a page is nearly full, then the vertical whitespace near the line is adjusted so that it runs into the section title and looks horrible.  I'd prefer if LaTeX just put the last line of the page onto the next page, rather than cramming it in and adjusting the whitespace.

In response to this problem, I've been trying to disable any kind of "glue" that I can find, but to no avail.  Mostly everything I've tried is in the examples below.  I'm including two examples, one in which the page isn't full, and one in which it is, so you can see the difference.  The first picture is from the code below, but with the second and third paragraphs removed.

I apologize if this issue has already been addressed elsewhere, but I can't find a good solution.  Also, please feel free to suggest improvements which are not directly related to my question.  This is the first time I'm building a template like this from scratch, and I'm sure I'm doing it wrong (and breaking all the rules of typography).  Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=.95in,right=.95in,top=.95in,bottom=.95in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\rightskip}{\leftskip}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-100pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\normallineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\addvspace{15pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} {\large{\textsc{#1}}}%
 \begin{center} \addvspace{-21pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} \line(1,0){474} \end{center}
 \addvspace{-10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} \par}
\newcommand{\plain}[1]{%
 \begingroup \addtolength{\leftskip}{1pt} \addtolength{\rightskip}{1pt} #1 \par \endgroup 
 \addvspace{5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}}

\begin{document}

\sect{Section}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See also [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75081) very similar question.

Comment: see http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88bazargan.pdf

Comment: Perhaps a mix of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84062/17423 and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` will get you the result you need.  At any rate, I'd use `\hrule` instead of `\line`.

Comment: Some of your settings are not obeyed, for instance `\baselineskip` will be the same as the default (and indeed 11pt with a 12pt font size would produce a very crowded and unreadable output). You forget that `center` adds `\topsep` glue.

Comment: upi can force the section title to have the depth of a descender by adding `\strut` to its content.  there will still be an attempt to close up available space, but the depth of the strut won't be recognized as space.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments.  egreg, it seems that the \topsep glue was actually the problem.  I removed the center environment and replaced \line with \hrule, as suggested by Sean, and it works fine now.  Steven, the article you posted looks really interesting, and I'm going to look into it further.  Unfortunately I can't figure out how to upvote any of your comments, but thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Even using TeX you need to make something by hand. So you may use `\pagebreak` somewhere inside last but one line or better on line last but two to avoid widow. Sometimes it is possible to allow widow lowering `\widowpenalty` value (`150` is the default value while `10000` should't allow any widow). However in your case even `\widowpenalty = 0` doesn't help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=.95in,right=.95in,top=.95in,bottom=.95in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{4pt}
\setlength{\rightskip}{\leftskip}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-100pt}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\lineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\normallineskip}{11pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}

\newcommand{\sect}[1]{\addvspace{15pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{\large{\textsc{#1}}}%
 \begin{center} \addvspace{-21pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} \line(1,0){474}\end{center}
\addvspace{-10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt} \par}
\newcommand{\plain}[1]{%
\begingroup \addtolength{\leftskip}{1pt} \addtolength{\rightskip}{1pt} #1 \par \endgroup 
\addvspace{5pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}}

\begin{document}

\sect{Section}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}
\plain{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   \pagebreak text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}

\end{document}
```